# Results in Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

Tags: r

I've downloaded this dataset, and when I plot it it is clearly non-stationary

```r
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ourcodingclub/CC-time-series/master/monthly_milk.csv')
plot(df,type="l")
```

But when I apply the Augmented Dickie-Fuller Test I get a p value of 0.01, implying that there is evidence to reject the null that the series is non-stationary.  I am puzzled as to why this is happening.  Is this because the confidence level is basically too high or is something else going on?

```r
adf.test(df[,2])

#> Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test
#> 
#> data:  df[, 2]
#> Dickey-Fuller = -9.9714, Lag order = 5, p-value = 0.01
#> alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

Thanks Nick Wray

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the ADF test includes a constant trend. Once you detrend your series, it does look stationary. Try the below

```
df$index <- seq(1,168,1)
lm(milk_prod_per_cow_kg ~index,data=df)
coef <- summary(lm(milk_prod_per_cow_kg ~index,data=df))$coefficients[2,1]
df$detrended <- df$milk_prod_per_cow_kg-df$index*coef
plot(df$detrended,type="l")
```

As you can see, the series always returns to something near the initial value after a few observations. The ADF checks for whether large jumps in a series are *persistent* i.e. have an effect on all the subsequent values in the series, after detrending the series. In this case the jumps are clearly temporary.

I don't have enough reputation to post images but here is an imgur link to a series that is non-stationary even after you de-trend it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsX45.png

Based on freely available data from FRED.

Comment: Ah yes I did wonder about that - if you take the first differences of the time series in my post you get a stationary series  Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that is incorrect. If a series is stationary only after you take the first difference, then it is *difference stationary* and the ADF test may give you a large p value. The low p-value you got is because the series appears to be *trend stationary*. There is a big difference between difference and trend stationarity, for example it is far easier to make predictions on trend stationary processes.